# XSLT get value of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Q Sequence="21" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Response>
    <Message ID="507"></Message>
  </Response>
</Q>
```

And this is the output I am trying to get from the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C>
    <Response>
        <ID>507</ID>
        <Sequence>21</Sequence>
    </Response>
</C>
```

My XSLT does not produce the expected outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Q">
    <C>
      <Response>
        <Id>
          <xsl:value-of select="/Message/@ID" />
        </Id>
      </Response>
    </C>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is far from what I'm trying to achieve but is this a better way to do this? This doesn't currently put the Id into the node. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/Q">
    <C>
        <Response>
            <Id>
                <xsl:value-of select="Response/Message/@ID" />
            </Id>
            <Sequence>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Sequence" />
            </Sequence>
        </Response>
    </C>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note**: A path that starts with `/` is an absolute path, starting at the root node.